# mod_rewrite with a domain that points to a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been looking to the answer to this question for a few days and can't seem to find it. I have a website, www.trportfolio.net, and on that, I am hosting an upload website www.trportfolio.net/upload/

I have purchased the domain www.truploader.com for that directory, and now I'm having trouble with a mod_rewrite. I need to rewrite this: www.truploader.com/view_upload.php?id=347343
to www.truploader.com/view/347343/

Please keep in mind that the actual path for both of these is www.trportfolio.net/upload/view_upload.php?id=347343. I believe it is because of this curveball that I'm having so much trouble figuring it out. I know I need a RewriteBase and a RewriteCond or two, but any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in an appropriate place in your document root's .htaccess file:

```
# won't need to turn on if it's already turned on in your htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ /upload/view_upload.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Comment: If I go to www.truploader.com/view/NUMBER I'm getting a 404.

Comment: So the view_upload.php file isn't in the /upload/ directory then? If not then remove the `/upload` from the rewrite rule.

Comment: The view_upload.php file is in the upload directory, yes.

Comment: Actually removing the /upload worked anyway! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I do have one more question. I have another file, search_results.php?searchtype=(filename/author)&query=QUERY

An example might be like: search_results.php?searchtype=filename&query=WeddingPicture

I need to turn that into www.truploader.com/filename/WeddingPicture/

Obviously there's going to be two variables, but this code that I just tried gave my entire site a 500 error.

`RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.+?)/ /search_results.php?searchtype=$1&query=$2 [QSA]`

Comment: The 500 could be from some kind of rewrite loop. But that string will never match because URI's in .htaccess have the leading slash stripped off. Try `^(.+?)/(.+?)/`. But that shouldn't cause the 500 error, which probably means it's conflicting with another rule somewhere. Note that **/view/123235/** will match that rule and get rewritten to **/search_results.php?searchtype=view&query=123235** if that is before the rule for view_upload.php

Comment: This is my entire .htaccess and I'm still getting a 500.

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_upload.php?id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/ /search_results.php?searchtype=$1&query=$2 [QSA]`

Comment: By the way, if it makes it easier, "searchtype" can only be either "filename" or "author". The search is done through a form on the previous page where the visitor must choose to search by filename or author. The following code does not work though, I still get a 500: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_upload.php?id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^filename/(.+?)/ /search_results.php?searchtype=filename&query=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/(.+?)/ /search_results.php?searchtype=author&query=$1 [L]`

Comment: If the first section is either *filename* or *author*, you may just want to create a rule for each one: `RewriteRule ^filename/([^/]+)/? search_results.php?searchtype=filename&query=$1 [L,QSA]` and one for **author**.